# When is the earliest mention of snowfall in hot deserts?

Tags: desert

In 2020 Saudi Arabia Experienced Unusually Heavy [**Snowfall.**](https://www.abc.net.au/news/2020-01-15/saudi-arabian-desert-covered-in-snow-by-powerful-storm/11871048)

> A powerful storm bringing sub-zero temperatures has transformed parts
> of the Saudi Arabian desert into a winter wonderland.

My search of records of snowfall in deserts returned with some current ones in [**Sahara.**](https://www.geographyrealm.com/often-snow-sahara-desert)

> There have been three recorded episodes of significant snowfall.  The
> first was recorded in 1979, the second in December of 2016, and the
> third most recently on January 7, 2018

I am interested in the earliest mention of the phenomenon of snowfall in any of the deserts of the world  in historical literature and that also includes religious scriptures like Bible , Quran etc. or any other history books   where this is mentioned.

There is no timeframe here and any mention before the above example will be fine, but the more ancient the better.

Comment: Not all the deserts are located in hot places. Among others, most of Antarctic is a desert. Therefore it seems like a pretty random question. Maybe asking about snow fall or snow in religious scriptures, if Greeks, Egyptians .. has noted snow would be a better defined one.

Comment: @Greg - Yes, Antarctic is a one , but there are many hot deserts. And this definitely is not a random question.I am not sure whether asking ref.  only from religious Scriptures is on topic here or not. So for safer side I kept that as in case no other mention found etc.

Comment: Snow isn't unheard of in the Gobi Desert, and other [cold desert](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desert_climate#Cold_desert_climates) areas. The question might benefit from making it clearer exactly what climate (eg: on the [Koppen Classification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%C3%B6ppen_climate_classification)) it is asking about.

Comment: @T.E.D. -  Yeah , But i think adding specific technical information and asking specifically about that will move the question more closer to earth-science Stack. I want to keep the question a bit casual . Besides specific technical query will make this post uninteresting.But I will look at the link and will try to add climate part as you suggested. Or will ask about deserts  from countries or regions.

Comment: It snows every once in a while in [Death Valley, CA](https://qph.fs.quoracdn.net/main-qimg-2c4cb7415001af300a2f76f7bb46ebbc-c).   Death Valley is about as [hot as it gets](https://www.nytimes.com/2021/07/10/us/west-heat-wave-death-valley.html#:~:text=In%20Death%20Valley%2C%20the%20high,ever%20recorded%20on%20the%20planet), having hit 134F.

Comment: I seem to recall Xenophon talking about marching through snow in a desert and then reaching the euphrates within a couple of days,  not sure if this area counts as a desert by a proper definition though.

Comment: What about deserts where it is too cold for precipitation?

Comment: @jos- According to classification suggested it's hot deserts only.